# Total values dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get total values of these table

```
building_weight_and_height = {'Floor': ['Roof','10th','9th','8th','7th','6th','5th','4th','3rd','2nd'],
                              'DL(kN)': [1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200],
                              'StoreyHeight': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4]}
```

Expected output:

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSoMk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way , i am sure there can be other ways :

```
import pandas as pd

dics = {'Floor': ['Roof','10th','9th','8th','7th','6th','5th','4th','3rd','2nd'],
     'DL(kN)': [1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200],
     'StoreyHeight': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Floor','DL(kN)','StoreyHeight'])
print (df)

df['Floor'] = dics['Floor']
df['DL(kN)'] = dics['DL(kN)']
df['StoreyHeight'] = dics['StoreyHeight']
totalDL = df['DL(kN)'].sum()
totalSH = df['StoreyHeight'].sum()
df=df.append({'Floor':'Total','DL(kN)':totalDL,'StoreyHeight':totalSH},ignore_index=True)
print (df)
```

Output as below:

```
    Floor  DL(kN)  StoreyHeight
0    Roof    1200             3
1    10th    1200             3
2     9th    1200             3
3     8th    1200             3
4     7th    1200             3
5     6th    1200             3
6     5th    1200             3
7     4th    1200             3
8     3rd    1200             3
9     2nd    1200             4
10  Total   12000            31
```

Comment: Thanks Rehan Azher

Comment: Cheers it helped.

Answer (score 0):

What are your problems?

```
>>> sum(building_weight_and_height['DL(kN)'])
12000
>>> sum(building_weight_and_height['StoreyHeight'])
31
```

Comment: How to add that answer into the dataframe. expected to be "Total, 12000, 31" but i'm getting "Total  Roof10th9th8th7th6th5th4th3rd2nd   12000            31"

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe from the dictionary and add a row using `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
import pandas as pd

building_weight_and_height = {'Floor': ['Roof','10th','9th','8th','7th','6th','5th','4th','3rd','2nd'],
                              'DL(kN)': [1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,1200],
                              'StoreyHeight': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(building_weight_and_height)
df = df[['Floor', 'DL(kN)', 'StoreyHeight']]

# alternatively:
# df = pd.DataFrame(building_weight_and_height, columns=['Floor', 'DL(kN)', 'StoreyHeight'])

df.loc[len(df.index)+1] = ['Total', df['DL(kN)'].sum(), df['StoreyHeight'].sum()]

print(df)

#     Floor  DL(kN)  StoreyHeight
# 0    Roof    1200             3
# 1    10th    1200             3
# 2     9th    1200             3
# 3     8th    1200             3
# 4     7th    1200             3
# 5     6th    1200             3
# 6     5th    1200             3
# 7     4th    1200             3
# 8     3rd    1200             3
# 9     2nd    1200             4
# 11  Total   12000            31
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(building_weight_and_height, columns=['Floor', 'DL(kN)', 'StoreyHeight'])` is better :)